# OPC DA/DCOM sample java source code, which can receive tags from server

Tags: java, sdk, opc, opc-da

I want to receive opc DA tags in a java code, to process it further.
I tried http://www.digitalpetri.com/ api but this receives data only from UA tags. It has a pattern matching, which invalidates the tag address of DA tags.

I am using Kepware to simulate data.

Does openOPC have a java implementation. I want to implement where I do not have to give security details.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use a UA toolkit to get data from an OPC-COM server. You'll need to use a tunneler product that converts COM/DA to UA and connect to that.

That being said... Kepware has support OPC-UA since version 5 or something like that, so maybe you can just use OPC-UA here.

Lastly, the digitalpetri project has officially migrated here: https://github.com/eclipse/milo

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, are there OPC DA java sdk available. Where I can avoid tunneling softwares and then read data directly in java programs?

Comment: @nandini I haven't used it myself, but it exists: http://openscada.org/projects/utgard/